# Circular horizontal Recycler View Adapter

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a horizontal Recycle View Adapter and I am trying to make it circular in both directions. I have found multiple solutions for this but none in Kotlin. My Adapter's getItemCount and onBindViewHolder look like this.

```
override fun onbindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder<T>, position: Int){ 
    val Data = items[position]
    holder.bind(Data, position, viewHoldBindFunc)

override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size
```

I have tried changing changing the two functions to the following but the Integer.MAX_VALUE makes the whole screen crash.

```
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {return Integer.MAX_VALUE}
and 
    override fun onbindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder<T>, position: Int){ 
        val NewPosition = position % items.size
        val Data = items[NewPosition]
        holder.bind(Data, NewPosition, viewHoldBindFunc)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution in Kotlin that seems to work. I based some of this code off of https://gist.github.com/nesquena/d09dc68ff07e845cc622.

It turns out that if you call a recycler adapter's notifyItemRemoved() and notifyItemInserted() methods (for a view you can't see), it will not move the position of the views you are currently looking at, but it will change what the RecyclerView perceives is to the right and to the left of you.

I got this working so I might as well share the result: This recycler adapter pretends there are 5 copies of the same set of items you show, and whenever an item from one of the furthest copies on the left or right are shown, it uses adapter.notifyItemRemoved() and notifyItemInserted() to shift the RecyclerView's perception to the side being scrolled towards.

You might need to test this a bit. It seems to work fine for me from scrolling through it for a few seconds. I put in 5 copies total just to be safe (1 in middle, two surrounding) but I bet this would work with 3 copies if you messed with it a little. :)

```
package com.github.ajsnarr98.testingplayground

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.github.ajsnarr98.testingplayground.databinding.ActivityCircularBinding

class CircularActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val list = listOf<Int>(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)

    lateinit var binding: ActivityCircularBinding
    lateinit var recyclerAdapter: CircularAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityCircularBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        recyclerAdapter = CircularAdapter(list, binding.list)
        binding.list.apply {
            adapter = recyclerAdapter
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@CircularActivity, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)
        }

        recyclerAdapter.init()
    }
}
```

```
package com.github.ajsnarr98.testingplayground

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class CircularAdapter(
        private val items: List<Int>,
        private val recyclerView: RecyclerView,
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CircularAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    var offset: Int = 0
    var numSets = 5

    val initialPosition = items.size * 2 // two sets of items before, two sets after

    fun init() {
        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(initialPosition)
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            // This happens many times a second during a scroll, so be wary of the code you place here.
            // We are given a few useful parameters to help us work out if we need to load some more data,
            // but first we check if we are waiting for the previous load to finish.'
            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                // this example only supports LinearLayoutManager
                val layoutManager: LinearLayoutManager = recyclerView.layoutManager as? LinearLayoutManager ?: return
                val firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
                val lastVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()

                if (isInBoundarySet(firstVisibleItemPosition)) {
                    insertItemsLeft()
                }
                if (isInBoundarySet(lastVisibleItemPosition)) {
                    insertItemsRight()
                }
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_number, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(itemForPosition(position))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size * numSets

    /**
     * Returns true if the given position is within items.size from 0 or
     * getItemCount().
     */
    private fun isInBoundarySet(position: Int): Boolean {
        return position + items.size >= itemCount || position - items.size < 0
    }

    private fun itemForPosition(position: Int) = items[position % items.size]

    /**
     * Pretends a new set of items was inserted to the right, and a set was was removed to the left.
     */
    fun insertItemsRight() {
        numSets--
        notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, items.size)
        numSets++
        notifyItemRangeInserted(itemCount, items.size)
    }

    /**
     * Pretends a new set of items was inserted to the left, and a set was was removed to the right.
     */
    fun insertItemsLeft() {
        numSets--
        notifyItemRangeRemoved(itemCount-items.size, items.size)
        numSets++
        notifyItemRangeInserted(0, items.size)
    }

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        fun bind(item: Int) {
            if (this.itemView is TextView) {
                this.itemView.text = item.toString()
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val NUMBER_VIEW = 0
    }
}
```

item_number.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/frame"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    tools:text="1"/>
```

activity_circular.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CircularActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Circular recycler view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/list"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

frame.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <!-- View background color -->
    <solid
        android:color="@color/white" >
    </solid>

    <!-- View border color and width -->
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="@color/black" >
    </stroke>

</shape>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It looks like addOnScroll is depreciated and I'm trying to find an alternate solution

Comment: No problem. addOnScrollListener is _not_ deprecated. See https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView#addonscrolllistener

Comment: None of the code I attached is deprecated as far as I can see from docs/warnings.

Comment: yes you are correct it is not depreciated, sorry!

Comment: I followed your implementation as much as possible. It gave me the idea I needed so hank you! I can loop going forward nicely but when I try to make it bi-directional in loading the screen I can see the scroll into the middle position. Do you know any trick I can use?

Comment: That was something I wasn't sure about when I messed around with this. For me, by scrolling to the middle position during onCreate, it didn't end up being visible. I remember noticing an internal function inside recyclerview that allowed for scrolling with no animation, but I think it was private.

One trick you could use would be to make the whole thing invisible, maybe with a placeholder while it animates the scroll, and then make it visible again when it has finished. Also my feeling is this implementation will need some messing with in the number of sets you report on the screen.

Comment: For example, if you have 3 items you are showing, and there is a 10th or more item shown on the screen, this will probably get really wonky because you will always be able to see the items on the edge that are getting "added" and "removed". If that is a problem, you could fix that by increasing numSets to something else.

Maybe decreasing "initialPosition" would reduce animation time at the beginning for you too?